# How to avoid division by zero error when calculating average value from entry in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

```
root = Tk()


def calc_avg():
    
    s = entry.get()
    digit_list = [float(x) for x in s]
    avg = sum(digit_list) / len(digit_list)
    b = f'{avg:.3f}'


    if avg >= 1.450:
        avg_value = Label(side_frame, text=employee + ":  " + str(b), font=('Helvetica 10 bold'), fg="green")
        avg_value.place(relx='0.03', rely='0.05')
    elif avg <= 1.449 and avg >= 1.400:
        lpd_value = Label(side_frame, text=employee + ":  " + str(b), font=('Helvetica 10 bold'), fg="orange")
        avg_value.place(relx='0.03', rely='0.05')
    else:
        avg_value = Label(side_frame, text=employee + ":  " + str(b), font=('Helvetica 10 bold'), fg="red")
        avg_value.place(relx='0.03', rely='0.05')

    avg_value.after(1000, calc_avg)

employee = "John"

main_frame = LabelFrame(root, width=650, height=500)
side_frame = LabelFrame(root, width=200, height=500)

main_frame.grid(row=0, column=0)
side_frame.grid(row=0, column=1)

label1 = Label(main_frame, text=employee, font=('Helvetica 12 bold'))
label1.place(relx='0.03', rely='0.05')

entry = Entry(main_frame, width=42, borderwidth=1, font=('Helvetica 12'))
entry.place(relx='0.22', rely='0.05')

calc_avg()

root.mainloop()
```

I've ran into a problem where when I input a string of digits into the entry box the program should calculate the average float value of those digits.

I have implemented the '''after()''' method so the value is updating in real time.

The problem is, when I start my program, since there are no digits in the entry box at the start, I get the ZeroDivisionError right away.

How do I make it so the label says "No value" when there is no input made instead of Error message; and the actual value when there is numerical input made?

Comment: A simple `if` maybe?

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing your code

Comment: We need to see a [mcve] to give specific help but as a guess just add an `if data:` block.

Comment: how do you avoid running a part of a program when a variable has a certain value?  ... it is same as running a part of a program when a variable has a certain value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you don't need the `str(b)` at the end since `b` is already a string. You can just use a simple if statement to check that the length is non-zero:

```py
def calc_avg():
    s = entry.get()
    digit_list = [float(x) for x in s]
    # check to make sure it has elements
    if digit_list:
        avg = sum(digit_list) / len(digit_list)
        b = f'{avg:.3f}'
    else:
        avg = None
        b = "No value"

    if avg is None:
        avg_value = Label(side_frame, text=employee + ":  " + b, font=('Helvetica 10 bold'), fg="red")
        avg_value.place(relx='0.03', rely='0.05')
    elif avg >= 1.450:
        avg_value = Label(side_frame, text=employee + ":  " + b, font=('Helvetica 10 bold'), fg="green")
        avg_value.place(relx='0.03', rely='0.05')
    elif avg <= 1.449 and avg >= 1.400:
        lpd_value = Label(side_frame, text=employee + ":  " + b, font=('Helvetica 10 bold'), fg="orange")
        avg_value.place(relx='0.03', rely='0.05')
    else:
        avg_value = Label(side_frame, text=employee + ":  " + b, font=('Helvetica 10 bold'), fg="red")
        avg_value.place(relx='0.03', rely='0.05')

    avg_value.after(1000, calc_avg)
```

Comment: If length of `digit_list` is zero, `avg` is undefined after the first if/else block.